# Create a map of all county fips codes which fall within a 50 mile radius from given zip code in Python

Tags: python, zip, zipcode, fips

I have dataset which has zip codes of different locations. 
I want to map each zip code to an array of FIPS codes (county FIPS,State FIPS for border counties) which fall within a 50 miles radius from the focal county where the zip code falls.

I am able to find pyZipCode to do a zip code extraction but am not sure how to map them to fips codes. There is an R package(noncensus) to do that. That is not available for python. I am wondering if there is a way to do this in python since this is a part of a bigger script in python.

Thank you in advance!!

[UPDATE] I found the map in a rather cumbersome format here https://wonder.cdc.gov/wonder/sci_data/codes/fips/type_txt/cntyxref.asp
There is no python package to do the mapping, probably because there could be multiple zip codes for a single county (like the border streets.. ) Thank you!

Comment: you can use geopy to calculate the great circle distance between two geographic points. So if you can reduce your data to geographic points (LON/LAT) then you could just calculate the distance between the two and filter things above 50 miles. This method probably brings some inaccuracies.

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful. Do you know if there is any package for the fips mapping? That killing me the most ! :)

Comment: Seems like this exists https://pypi.python.org/pypi/us